# Facebook Objective-C Chat API

Tags: objective-c, facebook, chat

I am looking for a Facebook Chat API on Objective-C. I have found one for Ruby (coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/facebook-chat-api/) and have noticed that software like Adium use it.

So what I would like to know is how I could make/find a working Framework for the FB Chat.

Thanks,
Alexandre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an opensource pigin plugin for facebook chat [hosted here](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/).

Looks like the whole thing is in C, so an Objective-C wrapper shouldn't be too painful to gin together.

Comment: OK Thanks but is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can call C methods directly from Objective-C.  Also, since Object-C is a strict superset of C you can directly embed C code/functions.  I don't think it gets any easier than that.